# SQL Server Agent service account login failure

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent

I am using SQL Server 2014 on a Windows 2012 server. I have several database instances on the server.

One of the instances has an error in the log every day at 2 AM.

> Login failed for user `MyDomain\SQLAgentAccount`.
>   Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.
>   [CLIENT: ].
>   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5

This is the service account used for SQL Server Agent. The Agent service is running and all jobs run successfully. I was able to trace it back to see that it is coming from PowerShell.

If I add the account explicitly, the error goes away. But I did not need to do that on the other instances and don't think it would be best practices to do so here.

Comment: In my Profiler trace, the application name field says "SQLPS (SQLAgentAccount@servername)" which is why I think Powershell is being called by the Agent service account and is failing.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am seeing the same exact issue on many instances, always at 2am, and always with the SQL Server service account.